# jQuery unable to get data attribute, returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, I am trying to get the data attribute of the following...

```
<a href="#" data-id="54" class="active">54</a>

var myid = jQuery("active").data("id");
```

Buit this is giving me an undefined error, where am I going wrong?

Comment: You forgot the period in front of the class name. It should be `jQuery(".acitve")`

Comment: There are many ways to get the result of data-attribute. You may check the result in answers. In current code you have missed class declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing "." before class selector. You need to do something like this to get the id attribute:

$(".active").attr("id");

Refer: https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 3):

`active` will select `<active>` elements, if you want to get elements that have this class name use `.active`.

Here is an example:

```
jQuery(".active")
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the attribute value of any tag you may use `attr()` method on the tag. Inside the `attr()` method you have to pass the custom data tag like `data-{attribute-teag-name}`

There are four different ways to get the result:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var id = $("#custom").attr("data-customid");
  console.log("attribute value with id -- ",id);
  var id_1 = $(".active").attr("data-customid");
  console.log("attribute value with class -- ",id_1);
  var id_2 = $(".active").data("customid");
  console.log("attribute value with class and data method -- ",id_2);
  var id_3 = $("#custom").data("customid");
  console.log("attribute value with id and data method -- ",id_3);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-customid="54" id="custom" class="active">54</a>
```

Comment: you could also explain what you've changed and why the OP code doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use `class selector (.)` .Moreover Class selector is not suited when you are looking to have multiple elements with same class (it will always return the first element).

```js
var myid = jQuery(".active").data("id");
console.log(myid)

// if you have multiple elements with same class

jQuery(".active").each(function() {

  let myid = $(this).data("id");
  console.log(myid)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-id="54" class="active">54</a>
<a href="#" data-id="55" class="active">55</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myid = jQuery(".active").data("id");
console.log(myid)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-id="54" class="active">54</a>
```

You were missing a "." in the selector - to tell jQuery you are selecting a class.

Answer (score 1):

if you are accessing class then add '.'(dot).
you code would be .

```
<a href="#" data-id="54" class="active">54</a>

var myid = jQuery(".active").data("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is "." missing before class selector, You can get the data-id attribute value by:

`$(".active").attr("data-id");`
or
`$(".active").data("id");`

> Getting data- attribute value by class so you have to use "." and by id "#" before the tag-name

Reference:

https://api.jquery.com/attr/

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-selectors

Answer (score 1):

You call `<active>` elements by `Jquery("active")`

Try

`var myid = Jquery(".active").data("id");`